# Edit View not passing data correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I'm trying to edit an element through the edit view. While debugging, I've noticed that the object I'm trying to update the database with has null or zeroed fields. The edit view seems to not return the data I'm entering.
Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace METALIMPEX.Models
{
    public class Condition
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Condition ID")]
        [Column("condition_id")]
        [Required]
        public int conditionID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date and time")]
        [Column("condition_date")]
        [Timestamp]
        [Required]
        public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Component ID")]
        [Column("component")]
        [Required]
        public int componentID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Operator ID")]
        [Column("operator")]
        [Required]
        public int operatorID { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Component status")]
        [Column("condition")]
        [Required]
        public bool condition { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Comments")]
        [Column("remarks")]
        [Required]
        public string comments { get; set; }
    }
    public class ConditionDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=DELL-XPS\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=METALIMPEX;Integrated Security=True");
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using METALIMPEX.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System;

namespace METALIMPEX.Controllers
{
    public class ConditionController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private ConditionDBContext db = new ConditionDBContext();
        IList<Condition> conditionList = new List<Condition>();

        public ConditionController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            //DEPRECATED CODE, MANUAL QUERY, PROJECT NOW USES DBCONTEXT
            /*string strConnection = "Data Source=DELL-XPS\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=METALIMPEX;Integrated Security=True";
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT   REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(RTRIM(PartID))) + RTRIM(PartID) AS 'Part ID', REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(RTRIM(OperatorID))) + RTRIM(OperatorID) AS 'Operator ID', Date_Time AS 'Time', IsPartWorking AS 'Part Status', IsMachineWorking AS 'Machine Status' FROM Defect";
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);
            SqlDataReader Dr;
            try {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                Dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (Dr.Read())
                {

                    conditionList.Add(new Defect()
                    {
                        conditionID = Dr["Part ID"].ToString(),
                        operatorID = Dr["Operator ID"].ToString(),
                        dateTime = Dr["Time"].ToString(),
                        partStatus = (bool)Dr["Part Status"],
                        machineStatus = (bool)Dr["Machine Status"]
                    });
                };
                Dr.Dispose();
            }
            catch (SqlException) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("An error has occured while connecting to the database");
                //OR
                //return View("Error");
            }*/
        }

        // GET: Condition
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
        //return View(conditionList);
        return View(db.Conditions.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Condition/Details/5
        public IActionResult Details()
        {
            return View(conditionList);
        }

        // GET: Condition/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Condition/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(Condition condition)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               //_context.Condition.Add(condition);
               //_context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(condition);
        }

        // GET: Condition/Edit/5
        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            if (conditionList == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            Condition condition = db.Conditions.Single(m => m.conditionID == id);
            return View(condition);
        }

        // POST: condition/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Edit(Condition condition)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Update(condition);
                db.Entry(condition).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(condition);
        }

        // GET: condition/Delete/5
        [ActionName("Delete")]
        public IActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            return View(conditionList);
        }

        // POST: condition/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            /*Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            db.Movies.Remove(movie);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");*/
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

View:

```
@model METALIMPEX.Models.Condition

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<form asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Condition</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="conditionID" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="componentID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="componentID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="componentID" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="operatorID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="operatorID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="operatorID" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input asp-for="condition" />
                    <label asp-for="condition"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="dateTime" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="dateTime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="dateTime" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="comments" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="comments" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="comments" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
```

I'm a beginner in .NET so I have no real idea what's wrong here. The edit view was generated by the framework so I assume it should be working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the **parameter name** of the **Edit** Action method. Below is the URL encoded form-data posted from the view on clicking **Save** button.

> conditionID=&dateTime=2013-12-01&componentID=1&operatorID=1&condition=true&comments=

The action parameter name is **condition** and there is a key-value pair **condition=true** in the incoming form-data. The [MVC model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529639/when-i-need-to-use-post-method-with-multiple-parameters-instead-of-separate-mode/42530614#42530614) process will try to map the parameter/property(in case of complex model) name to the corresponding **Route/Query String/Request Body** data.

Hence it's trying to map the value of **condition** in the form-data i.e. **true** to the action parameter and eventually fails to **convert bool** to **object**.

Change the parameter name to any name that doesn't corresponds to any key name in the form-data and it should work.

Comment: Removed every **ValidateAntiForgeryToken**, same result. `return View(condition)` is executed and I get the edit view with 0 or nothing in all fields, indicating that the condition object has empty fields for some reason.